# How can i fixed the npm run deploy problem

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages, webdeploy, uglifyjs

I am trying put my new react application on github pages but I cannot resolve some things...

I'm follow the tutorial on this link "https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages" and when i run the command "npm run deploy", the following message appears:

[Failed to compile.

static/js/main.9e58b467.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({) [./~/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.production.min.js:11,866]

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/arthur/.npm/_logs/2022-02-06T21_32_24_524Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0 predeploy: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 predeploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ3l2.png)

Things that I'm already try...

1. Install a webpack plugging with "npm install --save uglifyjs-webpack-plugin"
2. Delete the package-lock.json, the node-modules directory and clean the npm cache, and npm install again...

Please help! I don't know what to do now...

The link to the repository is https://github.com/ArthurBMessias/react-port

Comment: Github link returns 404 page

Answer (score 0):

Changing my "react-scripts" property in my `package.json` to version "5.0.0"

```
"react-scripts": "5.0.0"
```

worked for me!

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution Joshua, worked for me too!! 
I had to put another detail... I'm using react-router dom, so I had to put a property on him, so that the application can load all routes correctly,  the property basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} in the BrowserRouter component.

<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
//  Routes...
</BrowserRouter>

Comment: @ArthurBernardoMessias Thanks for this comment, I just ran into the same problem today and your comment literally saved me a day ! 